# Traps has blocked a malicious file when click AVD Manager android studio

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

How to prevent this error: `Traps has blocked a malicious file.` I got the error after I installed emulator in android studio in macOS Catalina. Every time I click AVD Manager or run android emulator, the error will be shown.

[image]